# How strong is Gintoki?

Tags: gintama

In episode 21 of the 2006 series, when Gintoki tries to buy a fan , apparently he gets involved in a fight where he breaks a car in 2 with a kick, and later he throws an object larger than him, presumably very heavy.

[image]

But since he was telling these events to Kagura, and Kagura said he made up this story of how he got the fan, we dont know if this really happened or not, despise the fan is signed by a girl which was involved in the events he told, asserting the story seems to be at least partially true.

My question is how strong is Gintoki? Does he has superhuman-level strenght? or is he just a skilled samurai with regular human strenght?

Comment: Well, previously Gintoki did slash a reactor into two...He pulled a friggin Helicopter down to Earth...he exchange blows with one of the 3 strongest races, the Yato...so at the very least he is far above average.

Comment: yeah, I saw now the episode where he brings down the helicopter. Which is weird because previously Kagura stopped a car in movement and everybody was surprised, but taking down a helicopter probably requires more strenght. And there is another episode where he and Katsura are completely overpowered and "kidnapped" by a trans samurai. I wonder how much strong is this samurai then??